# R: Is it possible that indexing matrices changed from "by row" to "by col"?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I wanted to calculate distances in R 3.1.1 from one point to a bunch of points:

```
p=c(1,2)
points=rbind(c(2,3),c(5,3),c(2,5))
p-points
```

From my experiences I thought the result should be:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -1
[2,]   -4   -1
[3,]   -1   -3
```

but I got:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -1
[2,]   -3   -2
[3,]   -1   -3
```

I realized that indexing was columnwise instead of rowwise. Did this change from one R version to the other or is my memory on that issue wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I know what calculation helps to get rid of the problem, but I'm asking myself if this changed within the last few versions. That whould mean I had to examine myriads of lines of code I wrote.

Comment: Ben Muller Could you specify the version which gives a different result?  I am using the new version `R version 3.1.1`, but I guess this was the same for the last few versions.

Comment: It's 3.1.1 as noted above. Seems like user20637 had the answer and pointed out that ther was no change and I messed it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your memory on that issue is wrong :-}
From `?array`

> The values in data are taken to be those in the array with the leftmost subscript moving fastest.

My memory isn't particularly reliable but I think this has been the case since I was first exposed to S-plus over a decade ago; I seem to recall being surprised when I first read it and filing it away in a "bear in mind" slot.

An indication that this choice dates back to FORTRAN days comes from An Introduction to R:

> 5.1 Arrays
>   ...
>
> The values in the data vector give the values in the array in the same order as they would occur in FORTRAN, that is “column major order,” with the first subscript moving fastest and the last subscript slowest.

Changing this choice would break so much code that I doubt greatly it has been changed, or would be without major discussion and warning.

Comment: Thank you for these insights. Looks like I messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors stored in R vertically to fix this issue you should use transpose.

Use this instead:

```
t(p-t(points))
```

Comment: Sorry, the time that I was writing the answer, there was not any answer!